# See the code below it is not structured properly so i restructure it and when ever i hit save it again jumbles back like this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react'

function Header() {
    return ( < div >

        <
        /div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Guys take a look this happens this destructing of HTML happens whenever I hit save in a react App I am not sure why I am using VS Code and I tried all the extensions to solve it but nothing helps

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable formatting on save option in Vs-code.
Path - Preferences/Settings/Formatting

Comment: it is already disabled and i tired again still the same scenario happens